# How to set different branches for different stages in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have the next pipeline:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('CLEAN/INSTALL') {
            steps {
                sh 'mvn clean install -DskipTests'
            }
        }
        stage('RUN ON DEV') { //run against branch 'default'
            steps {
                sh 'mvn test  -Dspring.profiles.active=dev'
            }
        }
        stage('RUN ON QA') { //run against branch 'qa-stable'
            steps {
                sh 'mvn test  -Dspring.profiles.active=qa'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to run tests in different stages against different branches:
How to achieve this?
Thanks!

Comment: Use different scm steps with required branches for each stage, or just add an sh step for each stage that runs 'git clean -dfx && git checkout $NEEDED_BRANCH'

Comment: @hopetds I use mercurial. Could you please provide an example or code sample. This is pure new topic for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add an sh 'git checkout blah'

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('CLEAN/INSTALL') {
            steps {
                sh 'mvn clean install -DskipTests'
            }
        }
        stage('RUN ON DEV') { //run against branch 'default'
            steps {
                sh 'mvn test -Dspring.profiles.active=dev'
            }
        }
        stage('RUN ON QA') { //run against branch 'qa-stable'
            steps {
                // might need to stash if you have any unignored files changed by your build
                sh 'git checkout qa-stable'
                sh 'mvn test -Dspring.profiles.active=qa'
                // you might also want to re checkout your original branch
            }
        }
    }
}
```